# Approximation: What can I put under the $\cal O$s

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, approximation

First, let me specify that $\cal O (X)$ denotes an (infinitesimal) amount that is of the **same** order with $\cal X$, i.e., $\lim \frac{\cal O(X)}{\cal X}=\text{constant}\ne0$ as $\cal X\to 0$. For example, when $x$ tends to $0$, it is well known that $\sin(x)=x+\cal O(x^3)$.
Now my two questions are what should be put under these two $\cal O$s:
(1). $$(1+\frac1n)^n=e+\cal O(?)$$
(2). $$(1+\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c})^n=1+\cal O(?)$$
Of course, $n\in\mathbb N$ and $n\to\infty$.

---

**My attempt**
For the first, I have tested out that it is $\cal O(\frac1n)$, when I let Maple calculate $\lim \frac{(1+\frac1n)^n-e}{\frac1n}$ it came out with the result $-\frac12e$. But for a rigorous proof  I don't really know where to start.
For the second, I have rewritten the LHS like this
$$LHS=\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c}\Bigr)^{(an^2+bn+c)\cdot\frac an}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c}\Bigr)^{-\frac ba}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c}\Bigr)^{\frac cn}$$
But it seems to get me nowhere.
Also, I have googled it but still don't get any desired result.
Any help or hint will be appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: Solve for the Taylor series of what you want to know the $O$ of. Then use that. You can approximate it to however many terms you like. Also note that your expressions of interest are nearly identical. You should be able to solve the first, then plug in the quadratic expression of the second and simplify.

Comment: @jdods But how? Do you mean taylor for $(1+x)^{\frac1x}$ at $0$?

Comment: @jdods Well, with the assistance of Maple I have made out that $$(1+x)^{\frac1x}=e-\frac12 ex+\cal O(x^2)$$ (to be specific $\cal O(x^2)$ here is $-\frac{1}{2!}\frac{11}{12}ex^2+\cal O(x^3)$). So my first question is done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to consider logging the function:$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e^{n \log (1 +\frac{1}{n})}$. You can now expand the log function in Maclaurin series to the desired order since $\frac{1}{n} \to_n 0$ and $e= \text{exp}(1)$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm stupid to not realize this.

Comment: ...after which you'll have to expand $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$, which assumes you are allowed to use both Taylor series expansion for log and exp functions.

Comment: That's very easy to do. But at that time I failed to realize that I could log the function into this.

Comment: My prof would kill me if he knew I forgot this method

Comment: haha no worries I'm not telling him/her :)

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
\left( 1+ \left( a{n}^{2}+bn+c \right) ^{-1} \right) ^{n} =
1+{\frac {1}{an}}-{\frac {2\,b-1}{2{a}^{2}{n}^{2}}}-{\frac {6
\,ca-6\,{b}^{2}+3\,a+6\,b-1}{6{a}^{3}{n}^{3}}}+{\frac {48\,bca-24
\,{b}^{3}+24\,ba-24\,ca+36\,{b}^{2}-12\,a-12\,b+1}{24{a}^{4}{n}^{4}}}+O
 \left( {n}^{-5} \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask what command you are using for this? When I type "taylor($(1+x)^{\frac1x}$,0,n=3)" etc it simply reports error for the function is not defined at $0$.

Comment: `u:=(1+1/(a*n^2+b*n+c))^n; asympt(u,n);`